# Using Multiple sets of numbiner for the Random function in java

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Alright I am trying to use the same random function to output diffrent sets of numbers.

Background:

I am developing a plugin for a server and am needing a number generator to make odd's of winning,

What i would like to happen is to pass my odds of winning through a random number generator to then run the code like this,

```
if ( ten == 0) {
  //ADD STUFF TO PLAYER
return Ten = true;
} else {
  return Ten = false;
}
if (twenty == 0) {
  //ADD STUFF TO PLAYER
  return Twenty = true;
} ECT......
```

I am using this line of code.

```
Random rnd = new Random();

int ten = rnd.nextInt(10);
int twenty = rnd.nextInt(20);
ect....
```

but after the 1'st call to the rnd it gives me syntax errors saying,

```
Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token
```

please help me i have been beating my head against the wall for the last 2 hours!

thank's in advance for your assistance.

EDIT:

```
public class RewardsExec {


//Registering class as part of the Mojovote Plugin
private Mojovote plugin;
public RewardsExec(Mojovote plugin) {
    this.plugin = plugin;
}

//setting up Random Number Generator
Random rnd = new Random();

ten = rnd.nextInt(10);
twenty = rnd.nextInt(20);
//Odd's Executuion

if (ten = 0) {
    return Ten = true;
} else {
    return Ten = false;
}
    if (twenty == 0 {
            return Twenty = true;
    } else {
            return Twenty = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a syntax error, which means that somewhere in your code, you wrote something that doesn't follow the rules of how Java is written. Though your code given does not follow proper coding style, it does not obviously have syntax errors, and we would have to see more code. Syntax errors are unrelated to minecraft and bukkit. If you get a Java IDE such as Netbeans or Eclipse, it will automatically highlight any lines that have syntax errors so that you can fix them easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As first, there are some errors in your code:

This line produces your syntax error:

```
if (twenty == 0 {
```

Change it...

```
if (twenty == 0) {
```

Aswell this line doesn't make sense:

```
if (ten = 0) {
```

You did a assignment there. Use == or equals() to compare something.

Your Algorithm looks pretty strange. Better use this Method:

```
public boolean drawNumber(int i) {

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int number = rnd.nextInt(i);

    if (number == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the whole section of code, as somewhere your syntax is wrong, it's impossible to say without seeing all of it.

Edit:

Now the code is added:

'ten = 0' needs to change to 'ten == 0' in order to do the comparison correctly.

you are missing a ')' on this line: (it should be after the zero)

```
if (twenty == 0 {
```

Also, I can't see where you've declared the variables ten and twenty, so try changing to this:

```
int ten = rnd.nextInt(10);
int twenty = rnd.nextInt(20);
```

Finally, none of this code is in a method, it's just within the class file. Is it supposed to be invoked statically when the class is constructed? or when a method is called?

Comment: I had no syntax errors before adding this and it, and when i add the 1st ten = ran.nextInt(10); it dosent come up with an error, but when i add the second int twenty = ran.nextInt(20); then the syntax error occurs. is there a way i can write a function to pass the numbers through then create an array of true/false's? And i added code.